# Como quebrar a linha da legenda no Google Charts

Tags: google-charts, cakephp-3

Na [Imagem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqxBz.png) (abaixo), mostra um modelo de como eu quero que a legenda fique. [image: Imagem 1]

Na [Imagem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9bro.png) (abaixo), mostra como está saindo (no caso, sem quebra de linha). [image: Imagem 2]

---

### Pergunta

*Como faço a quebra de linha da legenda no [<kbd>Google Charts</kbd>](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) ?*

---

### Código usado na [Primeira Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqxBz.png):  <kbd>SEM ERRO</kbd>

```html
/*
 * Gráfico TRIMESTRAL de linha
 */

 $indicador_trimestral[$vIndicador_key] = new GoogleCharts();

 $indicador_trimestral[$vIndicador_key]->type('LineChart');

 $indicador_trimestral[$vIndicador_key]->options(array(
        'width' => '600',
        'heigth' => '300',
        'title' => 'Gráfico trimestral de satisfação do ' .
                    $vIndicador_value['Indicador']['nome'],
        'titleTextStyle' => array('color' => 'blue'),
 ));

 $indicador_trimestral[$vIndicador_key]->columns(array(
        'trimestre' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Trimestre',
        ),
        'problemas' => array(
            'type' => 'float',
            'label' => $vIndicador_value['Indicador']['nome'],
        ),
        'Metas.meta' => array(
            'type' => 'float',
            'label' => 'Meta',
        )
 ));

 Após percorro um SQL (paginado) com os dados e adiciono cada linha no gráfico:

 foreach ($this->paginate() as $key => $item) :
         $indicador_trimestral[$vIndicador_key]->addRow(array(
             'trimestre' => $item[0]['trimestre'] . 'º Trimestre',
             'problemas' => $item[0]['problemas'],
             'Metas.meta' => $item['Meta']['meta']
         ));
 endforeach;
```

---

### Código usado na [Segunda Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9bro.png):  <kbd>COM ERRO</kbd>

```html
/*
 * Gráfico Bimestral de linha
 */

   $indicador_bimestral[$vIndicador_key] = new GoogleCharts();

   $indicador_bimestral[$vIndicador_key]->type('LineChart');

   $indicador_bimestral[$vIndicador_key]->options(array(
        'width' => '600',
        'heigth' => '300',
        'title' => 'Gráfico bimestral de problemas do ' .
                    $vIndicador_value['Indicador']['nome'],
        'titleTextStyle' => array('color' => 'blue'),
   ));

   $indicador_bimestral[$vIndicador_key]->columns(array(
        'bimestre' => array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'label' => 'Bimestre',
        ),
        'problemas' => array(
             'type' => 'float',
             'label' => $vIndicador_value['Indicador']['nome'],
        ),
        'Metas.meta' => array(
             'type' => 'float',
             'label' => 'Meta',
        )
   ));

   _Após percorro um SQL (manual) com os dados e adiciono cada linha no gráfico:_

foreach ($sql as $key => $item) :
    $indicador_bimestral[$vIndicador_key]->addRow(
          array('bimestre' => $item[0]['bimestre'] . 'Bimestre',
                'problemas' => $item[0]['problemas'],
                'Metas.meta' => $item['Meta']['meta']));
endforeach;
```

Comment: Você poderia anexar o código que está utilizando para gerar os gráficos?

Comment: Talvez esse exemplo possa ser útil https://jsfiddle.net/1q1avbxe/

Comment: Olhei seu exemplo @AderbalFarias, mas apesar de ele ser feito em `javascript` e eu ter feito no `cakephp`, a maneira de fazer é a mesma, tanto que no primeiro modelo eu fiz (conforme a primeira imagem) e ele separou em duas linhas cada coluna de cada registro, no segundo modelo que é o Bimestral (segunda imagem) ele faz ficar em uma linha só.

Comment: @CamiloSantos, acrescentado os códigos usados para gerar os gráficos, em ambas as imagens...